# Simplest online, interactive platform to play Dresden Files RPG on?

Tags: dresden-files, fate, online-roleplaying

I am looking to start an online Dresden File campaign, and looking for a web client to play the game on. For this I need

- Online chat
- Keeping track of players' stats (which both Gm and players can see)
- Fudge dice roller
- A quick and dirty way to draw out abstract zones, place players and enemies and etc.

OpenRPG looks needlessly complex. Are there any other options?

Comment: related: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/33/online-pnp-rpg-software

Comment: This could be split into four questions really -- some of them have already been more or less answered.

Comment: I think this is a good question because dfrpg (fate 3.0) is quite a bit different from dnd

Comment: Yeah, a gridded map tool wouldn't be much use, for starters.

Comment: Synchronous or asynchronous?

Comment: Mm.. what does this means? Does synchronous means the players can only reply when the GM has finished?

Comment: @Extrakun - Synchronous means "live" - like chatting over Skype or IM. Asynchronous means the players don't have to be there at the same time, like Play-by-forum

Comment: @extrakun synchronous means that if one person updates it, everybody gets the update either as soon as it's submitted or as it's being drawn/added (like a chatroom, but where people can see what you type as you type). Asynchronous means that everyone has to refresh after an update is made to see the update.

Comment: I have to agree this question isn't well differentiated from the earlier ones and that's probably why you're not getting many responses. Consider improving that other question instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[www.roll20.net](http://www.roll20.net) is a powerful tool and not so crazy complex.

Yes I tested for the fudge dice and it works great. You get GM notes and everyone else gets to see public info on characters, and they do have hand drawn or drag and drop web search built in for various bits.

I'm trying to build something right now, but I am a complete noob to PnP RPG's. This in fact would be my first attempt so I'd much rather get in on someone elses campaign to learn the ropes.

Comment: It does have Fudge dice rolling too, which is awesome: http://help.roll20.net/dice-rolling-reference/

Comment: I love roll20. Its very modular and the ability to favorite anything you add (music, images, files, etc.) is so great.

basically there is a lot of modular design when you create characters and tokens within the system to support multiple gaming systems, but you can use whatever you want. I'd highly suggest macros for attack and power roles.

Answer (score 3):

[MapTool by RPTools](http://www.rptools.net/index.php?page=maptool) is a Java-based tool that can do all of that, though it's a generic platform, so you'd have to build some of it yourself to get started. But it looks like someone has already created a [Fate 3.0 generic framework](http://forums.rptools.net/viewtopic.php?f=33&t=16885&hilit=Dresden%20File) that could give you a starting point.

MapTool has text chat built in, along with player-controlled tokens that have "Properties" defined by the GM (can keep track of player stats), has a die roller integrated into the chat window which includes [Fudge dice rolling](http://lmwcs.com/rptools/wiki/fudge), and the map/token functionality can be used to create maps ahead of time with tiles/images, or draw freehand with paint tools to define areas. Additionally, MapTool tokens can have individual macros defined, so often-used rolls (skill checks) can be rolled easily with a button press.

I used OpenRPG prior to switching to MapTool, and MapTool is amazingly easy to set up (nothing to install; it's just a Java JAR) and use. Plus it has additional functionality like "status" indicators on tokens, life bars on tokens, vision/fog of war automation, spell templates, "hidden"/GM-only tokens (for hiding traps until they're visible), and more, if you want to use them.